# como tomar el nombre de una columna si coincide con el id de otras dos tablas SQL

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql

Estoy tratando de armar una consulta en la cual tengo ya las tablas de  referencia, mismas que me arroja, pero tengo la columna `T0.[U_IJAM_catedit]`, de esta me aparece el `ID` que se supone va ligado a mi otra tabla `UFD1`

Misma que es la siguiente en la imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entonces, lo que quiero es mostrar el campo descripción que coincide con mi tabla cuando la mando a llamar. A continuación agrego la consulta que me muestra el campo `descripcion`, pero solo el `ID`, mas no el nombre que necesito de mi otra tabla.

```
SELECT T0.[OpprId], T0.[CardCode], T11.[Name] as 'Tipo de Cliente',T12.[OrlDesc] as 'Nivel Educativo', T0.[U_IJAM_RelatCard], T0.[U_IJAM_Memo], T13.[Descr] as 'Numero Alumnos',T0.[U_IJAM_catedit]  , T0.[U_IJAM_Libro], T0.[U_IJAM_CompetId], T0.[U_IJAM_ThreatLevl], T0.[U_IJAM_Memo2], T0.[U_IJAM_Won], T0.[U_IJAM_Alumnos2], T0.[U_IJAM_AVCM],T15.[Won] as 'Perdidos por otros motivos' 
FROM OOPR T0
FULL OUTER JOIN OPR2 T10 ON T0.[OpprId] = T10.[OppOrTId] 
FULL OUTER JOIN OPRT T11 ON T10.[ParterId] = T11.[PrtId] 
FULL OUTER JOIN OORL T12 ON T10.[OrlCode] = T12.[OrlCode] 
FULL OUTER JOIN UFD1 T13 ON T0.[U_IJAM_Alumnos] = T13.FldValue and t13.TableID ='AOPR' AND t13.FieldID ='4'
FULL OUTER JOIN OPR3 T15 ON T0.[OpprId] = T15.[OppOrTId]

FULL OUTER JOIN UFD1 T14 ON T0.[U_IJAM_catedit] = T13.FldValue and t13.TableID ='OOPR' AND t13.FieldID ='5'

WHERE T0.[OpprId] ='17127'
```

Aca dejo la consulta a mi otra tabla, que es donde halaría la información:

```
SELECT *
FROM UFD1
WHERE fIELDID ='5' AND TABLEID = 'oopr'
```

copio datos de la tabla

```
Tabla   Campo   Índice  Valor   Descripción Valor de fecha  
OOPR    5       1   RICHMOND PREESCOLAR     
OOPR    5   1   2   BUILD & GROW BACHILLERATO       
OOPR    5   2   3   BUILD & GROW BUSINESS & PROFESSIONAL        
OOPR    5   3   4   BUILD & GROW EXAMS      
OOPR    5   4   5   BUILD & GROW PREESCOLAR     
OOPR    5   5   6   BUILD & GROW PRIMARIA       
OOPR    5   6   7   BUILD & GROW SECUNDARIABUILD & GROW SECUNDARIA      
OOPR    5   7   8   BUILD & GROW UNIVERSITARIO      
OOPR    5   8   9   CAMBRIDGE BACHILLERATO      
OOPR    5   9   10  CAMBRIDGE BUSINESS & PROFESSIONAL       
OOPR    5   10  11  CAMBRIDGE EXAMS     
OOPR    5   11  12  CAMBRIDGE PREESCOLAR        
OOPR    5   12  13  CAMBRIDGE PRIMARIA      
OOPR    5   13  14  CAMBRIDGE SECUNDARIA        
OOPR    5   14  15  CAMBRIDGE YOUNG ADULTS      
OOPR    5   15  16  CENGAGE BACHILLERATO        
OOPR    5   16  17  CENGAGE BUSINESS & PROFESSIONAL     
OOPR    5   17  18  CENGAGE EXAMS       
OOPR    5   18  19  CENGAGE PREESCOLAR      
OOPR    5   19  20  CENGAGE PRIMARIA
```

agregando descripcion a mi columna

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Para comenzar, podrías publicar los datos de la tabla como texto, no como imagen. Hablando sobre tu consulta, no logro entender tu pregunta. Has referenciado 3 veces ya la tabla UFD1 en los `joins`, sin embargo, ni utilizas cada referencia para encontrar datos en otras tablas, ni muestras nada en el select de ninguna de ellas. Creo que podrías aumentar tus probabilidades de encontrar ayuda si simplificas la consulta para elaborar un [mcve], incluyes los datos de entrada, la salida que esperas y una breve explicación del problema que tienes para conseguir llegar al resutlado.

Comment: ya corregi un poco mas la tabla l cuestion es que hago referencia a mi columna T0.[U_IJAM_catedit] la cual debe trer informacion de mi tabla UDF1 que son los nombres de la descripcion

Comment: lo que necesito e smi columna descripcion ya que si el id el igual al id entonces sera ese nombre entonces seria estas columnas de ambas tablas --> 0.[U_IJAM_catedit] = T13.FldValue

Answer (score 0):

Cuando tienes *joins* hacia la misma tabla, utilizas *alias*, que son nombres o apodos con los que identificas a una tabla o vista en el contexto de una consulta.

Veamos un ejemplo sencillo:

Tenemos las siguientes tablas:

```
Persona
---------------
idPersona
Nombre

Materia
---------------
idMateria
Materia

Tutoria
---------------
idTutoria
idPersonaAlumno
idMateria
idPersonaTutor
```

Y queremos, en una consulta, listar todas las tutorías con el nombre del alumno y el nombre del tutor, donde, como se ve, ambos vienen de la tabla `Persona`. Lo que veremos en el ejemplo a continuación es que se referencia la tabla `Persona` dos veces en la consulta, una con el *apodo* `alumno` y otra con el *apodo* `tutor` a patrir de allí nos referiremos a los campos de ESA referencia a la tabla a través del alias que dimos a la misma. Incluso en la condición de cada *join*, que tiene la condición adecuada para ubicar al registro correspondiente en la tabla `persona` y, en la lista de campos, obtenemos el nombre de cada persona **calificando** el nombre de la columna con el alias de cada tabla:

```
select   Tutoria.idTutoria
       , Alumno.Nombre AS Alumno
       , Materia.Materia
       , Tutor.Nombre AS Tutor
  from Tutoria
       inner join Materia on Materia.idMateria = Tutoria.idMateria
       inner join Persona AS alumno on alumno.idPersona = Tutoria.idPersonaAlumno
       inner join Persona AS tutor on tutor.idPersona = Tutoria.idPersonaTutor
```

Como puedes observar, también he asignado *alias* a las columnas que devolverá la consulta, a manera que no haya confusión en cual es cual.

He utilizado la palabra reservada **`as`** para resaltar mi intención, pero esta palabra puede obviarse y muchas personas —yo incluido— nunca la escriben.

Para ir a tu caso específico, si quieres incluir la descripción asociada a la tabla `UFD1` con el alias `T14`, agrega `T14.Descripcion` a las columnas del `select`. Recuerda que puedes ponerle un alias para dar claridad al resultado.

Comment: ya lo hice y me aparecio de la siguiente forma lo puse en mi pregunta

Comment: lo quise agregar asi 
inner join UFD1 AS Descr1 on fIELDID ='5' AND TABLEID = 'oopr'
y nombrar asi 
T14.Descr

Comment: ¿Leiste mi respuesta con atencióna? Si les estás poniendo de alias `Descr1`, después ¿eor qué quieres referenciar a ella con `T14`?. Creo que te estás apresurando, lee la respuesta, asegurate de entender la idea y hasta entonces modifica tu consulta.

Comment: lo agregue asi T14.[Descr] y no me devolvio nada en ese campo

Comment: que seria este -->FULL OUTER JOIN UFD1 T14 ON T0.[U_IJAM_catedit] = T13.FldValue and t13.TableID ='OOPR' AND t13.FieldID ='5'

Comment: Amigo, escribí una respuesta genérica para que tu puedas encontrar los errores en tu código. Esto es porque la pregunta es algo confusa. Estoy seguro que si entiendes mi respuesta, entiendes la consulta que tienes y el resultado al que quieres llegar, puedes corregirla por ti mismo. Yo no puedo decirte que campo utilizar o que alias, porque no tengo claro ni lo que buscas ni el estado en el que está la consulta que publicas, ni me siento motivado a hacer más esfuerzo por entenderla.

Comment: ¿Por qué tienes la condición del _join_ de `T14` con puras referencias a `T0`y `T13`? Qué es lo que buscas obtener de `T14`? ¿Por qué esas condiciones donde no se menciona a `T14` te van a dar la o las filas de `T14` que buscas? Creo que no hay manera así... si da algún resultado en `T14` va a ser por puro chance...

Comment: a ya conrazon es que en si lo que tratoi de hacer es eso mismo del ejemplo que me diste   -->   inner join Persona AS alumno on alumno.idPersona = Tutoria.idPersonaAlumno
pero me aparece eso en la descr
INNER  JOIN UFD1 T14 ON T0.[U_IJAM_catedit] = T13.FldValue and t13.TableID ='OOPR' AND t13.FieldID ='5'

Comment: ¡La condición del join es incorrecta!

Comment: a ya entiendo creo que por eso sale en balnco